# Which smooth closed curve has the highest area to perimeter ratio?

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I was thinking of what way to loop a string of a given length such that area inside is maximum. The reason I mentioned smooth in the question is because if we had a mathematical string, then we could deform tiny segments making bumps on the perimeter and reach an infinite perimeter.

---

**My attempt:** Let's assume the curve to be $\gamma(t)$ and let the parameter domain be $\left[ 0, t_{max} \right]$ then the arclength is given as:

$$ L  = \int_0^{t_{max} } \sqrt{ \dot{\gamma} \cdot \dot{\gamma} } dt $$

Note: The above arclength is fixed.

The area of the parametric curve maybe given by [gauss's shoe lace formula](https://youtu.be/0KjG8Pg6LGk?t=748) in vector form:

$$ A=  \int_0^{t_{max} } \gamma \times \dot{\gamma} dt$$

And, now, we want to optimize:

$$ S = \frac{A}{L} = \frac{\int_0^{t_{max} } \gamma \times \dot{\gamma} dt}{\int_0^{t_{max} } \sqrt{\dot \gamma \cdot \dot{\gamma} } dt}$$

I suppose the above is a calculus of variations question, but I haven't learned the tools to solve it. Still, could someone write a solution? I am interested in what would be the answer to this optimization problem.

Comment: Google "Dido's problem"

Comment: The ratio $A/L$ can be made arbitrarily large (try a circle with arbitrarily large radius), but it is bounded above by $L/4\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this problem well known as [dido's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dido) and the answer is a circle.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is in fact the isoperimetric problem. In that case, you want to optimize $A/L^2$, not $A/L$. Think about units.